# Get a list of subclasses of my entity in Doctrine 1.2

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

Is there a method I can call to obtain the name of all the mapped subclasses of an entity?

Comment: Not in a straightforward way. Can you give some info on the underlying problem that needs solving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do $tableClass->getOption("subclasses")

Although this will only work for types of inheritance where there is a discriminator map.  Most notably, you won't get it with concrete table inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
$relations = Doctrine_Core::getTable('<CLASS_NAME>')->getRelations();

foreach($relations as $relation)
  echo $relation->getClass();
```

Comment: Not relations, subclasses.  As in inheritance.